# How to add new steps or tab to checkout page in Magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento-2.0

How to add new tab or step in checkout page of magento2, that i need one more step in checkout page how to do it

Comment: What you have tried so far

Comment: i am not getting ui tags used in the checkout page and also flow can you help me on this

Comment: Me also.I think you should have idea knockout.js in addition to layout xml etc.

Comment: I think a good place to start looking is in the `checkout_index_index.xml` file within the `magento/magento-checkout` module.

Comment: Side note, the official documentation provides a good article about that: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html

Comment: @pradeep I also follow the link which is provide by Magento Team http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_form.html But how you are saving the data as i need to add new step same as billing

Comment: #John
Have any update on billing in shipping section

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179399/show-billing-address-form-in-checkout-first-step-in-magento-2

So please update me

Answer (score 8):

finally i got the solution, follow below steps for adding new tab or step for checkout page in Magento2

**app\code\Sugarcode\Test\view\frontend\layout\checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="mynewstep" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Sugarcode_Test/js/view/checkout/my-step-view</item>
                                                    <!--To display step content before shipping step "sortOrder" value should be < 1-->
                                                    <!--To display step content between shipping step and payment step  1 < "sortOrder" < 2 -->
                                                    <!--To display step content after payment step "sortOrder" > 2 -->
                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <!--add here child component declaration for your step-->
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app\code\Sugarcode\Test\view\frontend\web\template\checkout\mystep.html**

```
<!--The 'step_code' value from the .js file should be used-->
<li id="mynewstep" data-bind="fadeVisible: isVisible">
<div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: 'Step Title'" data-role="title"></div>
    <div id="checkout-step-title"
         class="step-content"
         data-role="content">

        <form data-bind="submit: navigateToNextStep" novalidate="novalidate">
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <div class="primary">
                    <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
                        <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Next'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</li>
```

**app\code\Sugarcode\Test\view\frontend\web\js\view\checkout\my-step-view.js**

```
define(
    [
        'ko',
        'uiComponent',
        'underscore',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
    ],
    function (
        ko,
        Component,
        _,
        stepNavigator
    ) {
        'use strict';
        /**
        *
        * mystep - is the name of the component's .html template,
        * my_module - is the name of the your module directory.
        *
        */
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Sugarcode_Test/checkout/mystep'
            },

            //add here your logic to display step,
            isVisible: ko.observable(false),


            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
                // register your step
                stepNavigator.registerStep(
                    //step code will be used as step content id in the component template
                    'mynewstep',
                    //step alias                    
                    'mynewstep',
                    //step title value
                    'My Step Title',
                    //observable property with logic when display step or hide step
                    this.isVisible,

                    _.bind(this.navigate, this),

                    /**
                        * sort order value
                        * 'sort order value' < 10: step displays before shipping step;
                        * 10 < 'sort order value' < 20 : step displays between shipping and payment step
                        * 'sort order value' > 20 : step displays after payment step
                    */
                    15
                );

                return this;
            },

            /**
                        * The navigate() method is responsible for navigation between checkout step
                        * during checkout. You can add custom logic, for example some conditions
                        * for switching to your custom step
                        */
            navigate: function () {
                var self = this;
                //getPaymentInformation().done(function () {
                    self.isVisible(true);
               // });

            },


            navigateToNextStep: function () {
                stepNavigator.next();
            }
        });
    }
);
```

***Note:-*** `run  bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy` and upgrade script which enable your module and also to move `.js` and `template` files to `Magento2/pub/static` fodler

Comment: Can you please explain how can we add a form to newly added checkout step in magento 2?

Comment: please check this post https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187847/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-checkout-page-in-magento2 , where i added one filed

Comment: i found some folders different from the original documentation please check:  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html

Comment: @PradeepKumar, Can we have newly added step as first step in the checkout? Also the content of that step is cart page?

Comment: @jafarpinjar did you able to show new step in first step ?

Comment: you can check the article for add review step, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/add-a-new-step-in-checkout-page-magento-2/

Comment: @PradeepKumar How did you show the cart page in custom step?

Comment: @Siva in order to display it in the first you need to change 15 in this file "my-step-view.js" to be less than 10, see this comment (* 'sort order value' < 10: step displays before shipping step;)

Answer (score 0):

For people interested for by a fully implemented Three Step Checkout extensions,
check this https://www.3step-checkout.com/