# How to add a new step in checkout

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, checkout-page

I had installed some **extension** to add an **step** and two **input fields** in **Magento 1.9**.
But currently i am using magento 2.1 and there is no any free extension available.

- Please let me know if any free extension available to achieve this.

**OR**

- I don't have much idea about magento **2.1**, please guide me to add
  an step with 2 fields. This step is optional for customer.

Below is the screen shot of version 1.9 which i need in magento 2.1 thanks.
[image: Checkout additional step]

Answer (score 1):

This Question has already been asked (adding new step) so may time, there is magento official document for this.

You can refer these:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html

[How to add new steps or tab to checkout page in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93283/how-to-add-new-steps-or-tab-to-checkout-page-in-magento2)

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as I know Magento does not offers any free extension for this. This comes under customization work. You have to contact a development team in order to customize the checkout step.

Hope this was helpful.