# Magento 2: Call extension on new checkout tab

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs

**To create the new tab on the checkout page I used this link and it is working** [How to add new steps or tab to the checkout page in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93283/how-to-add-new-steps-or-tab-to-checkout-page-in-magento2)

**I want to display this extension on new created tab**
[magento2-module-delivery-date](https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-delivery-date/tree/master/SR/DeliveryDate)

**Can anyone know how can I call delivery date extension on newly created tab?**

Comment: Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: I have created New Tab on Checkout Page but i cant set custom phtml file so please help someone