# Magento 2 add new checkout step under Shipping Step

Tags: checkout, magento2.2.2, shipping-step

How to add new step under shipping step not new step progress bar, the same as Shipping Method step is under Shipping Step progress bar?

like the screen shoots:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Magento Doc tells you how to add new step which will also create step progress bar but I need to achive a step inside the shipping Step: ref: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html

NOT This:
[image]

Comment: please follow this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93283/how-to-add-new-steps-or-tab-to-checkout-page-in-magento2

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel I've done that it creates new Step progress bar my friend I don't need it, maybe this is the only way perhaps then I shouldn't stepNavigator.registerStep ?

Comment: So what you need mate

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel A custom step in Shipping step like the screen shoot attached not extra step progress bar

Comment: Okay I will tell you